# PHP jquery database instant search no autocomplete in form

Tags: php, jquery, database

I was coding some php, jquery and database combo scripts to create an instant search but ran into the problem of the instant search results being overlapped by the automatic autocomplete of the browser. Is there a way around this nuisance?

Comment: `autocomplete="off"` on the form in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `autocomplete="off"` in the input control, and if the control is in a form then in the form control.
Example:

```
<form autocomplete="off" ... >
```

Or

```
<input autocomplete="off" ... />
```

Comment: Well that was pretty simple. Thanks!